# What is this compact 35mm camera from the 1990s?

Tags: film, compact-cameras, camera-identification

My now passed away father took this photo of me in the 1990s. My guess is that it's a Nikon. He owned a number of Nikon SLRs. Is anyone able to identify the camera? (Sorry about the shaky photo).

[image]

Comment: Please edit your title to describe the specific camera. Basically everything from [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) also applies here.

Comment: http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/1/49860/805296/halinafront_7.png

Comment: definitely appears to be a Halina Vision, but I can't see the exact model...  [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=classic+nikon+viewfinder&newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=985&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifrdDmn97MAhVKI8AKHfPtBqEQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACYeMWJMX89V7Ijgt3v6y8s1YVbFQOhBnXtSslKb2RTJIgfy8yqzJFa-Uegr5qTW2vh_1euShAc1L2XaosMUjOQHiwcioSCS3e_1rLyzVhVEaRUPdszN1oeKhIJsVA6EGde1KwRjXmajPV6SYcqEgmUpvZFMkiB_1BFie4VdXZOmaioSCbzKrMkVr5R6ETFH-4SLQzrAKhIJCvmpNba-H94RO7R_1YI0Ar9kqEgm5KEBzUvZdqhEeNVKY0Q_1F9yoSCSwxSM5AeLByEdn1WKT3ld_1E&q=halina%20vision&imgrc=_)

Comment: @dav1dsm1th [Please post that as an answer rather than a comment](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge). While it's not a complete answer to the question, it's definitely going in the right direction and someone can always improve your answer if they *can* work out which model it is.

Comment: I totally forgot about Fido Dido! Until now... :-)

Comment: @Chabeet Is there a possibility the camera was purchased originally in Australia or New Zealand?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to be one of the [Hanimex](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Hanimex) Vision series of cameras, possibly a Vision III. Hanimex was a company that imported cameras to Australia and New Zealand. They were founded shortly after WWII and early on they imported European and Japanese cameras branded under the Hanimex name. In the following years they also marketed flashes and lenses made by several manufacturers under the Hanimex brand name. They were also the exclusive distributors of Fuji cameras and photographic products in Australia and New Zealand from 1954. Following a series of transactions that saw Hanimex bought and sold by several holding companies, in 2004 Fuji Corporation acquired ownership of the Hanimex brand and discontinued the use of the name, although they still own the rights to it.

The Hanimex Vision series of cameras were very similar to some Halina camera models and were very likely manufactured by Haking of Hong Kong, the same company that made the Halina line.

Here's an image of a Hanimex Vision III recently offered for sale by [ozcamera.com](http://www.ozcamera.com/hanimex35.html). These cameras were often offered in a variety of colors.

[image: Hanimex Vision III]

I've not been able to find any example of a Halina Vision model beyond the initial 'Vision' (with no additional model naming) where the model name is printed up next to the lens opening as pictured in the image from the question and as pictured in the example above. With the Halinas the "Vision" is always printed down in the lower right corner of the front of the camera. None of the pictures I could find of DX (auto film speed detecting) capable Halinas had the distinctive "DX" marking that is visible just below the shutter button in the both the photo in the original question and in the example above. And none of the initial Halina 'Vision' models had DX automatic film speed detection capability.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is a Nikon One Touch. My mom had one of these.

Comment: Why do you believe that given dav1dsm1th's comment and rather convincing Google link?